# How to get a dictionary from Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dictionary, asp.net-core

I have three classes. The first class call AddInfo method of Data class. Then the Data class instantiate the dictionary. Finally, the controller class call the getDictionary method. 
It gives me an error: **KeyNotFoundException: The given key 'info' was not present in the dictionary.**

HomeController.cs

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    Data d = new Data();
    var getDic = d.getDictionary();

    var Info = getDic["First"];

    return View(Info);
}
```

Data.cs

```
public interface IData 
{
     Dictionary<string, object> getDictionary();
     void AddInfo(string infoName, TheObject obj);
}

public class Data : IData 
{
    public Dictionary<string, object> infoList;

    public Data()
    {
        infoList = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }

    public Dictionary<string, object> getDictionary()
    {
        return this.infoList;
    }

    public void AddInfo(string infoName, TheObject obj)
    {
        infoList.Add(infoName, obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line is the one where the error is happening? Can you post the code where objects are added to the `Data` class?

Comment: @howcheng The error occur at "var Info = getDic["First"];" 
It looks like dictionary is called before the information added to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "Data" object reference is created in your HomeController class on this line:

```
Data d = new Data();
```

and then almost immediately afterwards you try and access it on the following line:

```
var Info = getDic["First"];
```

At no point do you call `d.AddInfo("first", testObject)` or anything similar.
If you have another instance of the Data class somewhere else, then remember that these are two entirely separate objects and therefore don't share the same dictionary.

If you have an instance of the Data class created somewhere else higher up then a possible solution may be that you need to pass it in to the Index method as follows:

```
public IActionResult Index(IData d)
{
    var getDic = d.getDictionary();

    var Info = getDic["First"];

    return View(Info);
}
```